# Positive definite to nonnegative

Tags: linear-algebra, nonnegative-matrices

A simple question that I was pondering on while examining some algorithms that work similarly for positive definite and nonnegative matrices.

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the space of (let's say for now $2\times 2$) Hermitian positive-definite matrices. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the space of entrywise nonnegative matrices of the same dimension.

One can define a linear map $\Phi:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{P}$ in many ways; for instance,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b+id\\b-id & c
\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
a & a+c+b\\a+c+d & c
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Is there a such a linear map that preserves matrix squaring, i.e., a map $\Phi: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{P}$ such that

1. $\Phi(tH)=t\Phi(H)$ for each $t >0 $,
2. $\Phi(H+K)=\Phi(H)+\Phi(K)$,
3. $\Phi(H^2)=\Phi(H)^2$  ?

Comment: Requirement 3 almost requires the map $\Phi$ to be multiplicative, which means that only maps of the form $\Phi(X) = X \otimes I$ etc. might fulfill the condition, so the answer to your question might be "no"...

Comment: Hi Suvrit! What do you mean by multiplicative in this context? The product of two Hermitian matrix is not Hermitian in general. Also, if one drops the positivity requirement, if I have made no mistakes then $\begin{bmatrix}a & b+id\\b-id & c\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}a & b+d \\ b-d & c\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies 1.--3. and is not the trivial map.

Comment: Do you mean "nonnegative semidefinite" when you say "positive definite"? I'm asking because I see $t\geq 0$ in 1., rather than $t > 0$.

Comment: That's why I said "almost" because 3. is saying: $\Phi(H H) = \Phi(H)\Phi(H)$; though of course $\Phi(HK)$ might not be even defined for arbit Hermitian $H$ and $K$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'd be fine with a solution working for either pos-def or nonneg-def. You are right about the inconsistency, though, I'll correct $t\geq 0$.

Comment: An obvious (and useless) example is $\Phi(H) = 0$. What other properties should $\Phi$ have (injectivity, for example)?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how your example $\begin{bmatrix}a & b+id\\b-id & c\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}a & b+d \\ b-d & c\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies $3$. When I square the left side, I get the top left element $a^2+b^2\color{red}{+}d^2$, but when I square the right side, I get $a^2+b^2\color{red}{-}d^2$ and, by your map, they should be the same. What am I missing?

Comment: @Vedran: typically one requires $\Phi(I)=I$ to prevent degeneracies like the one you mentioned...

Comment: @suvrit I know, but it would still be useful that OP says what exactly does he want. He did say this came from some algorithms he was researching.

Comment: @Vedran: true, true :-) Hopefully Federico tells us what further restrictions there might be.

Comment: Hi Vedran, it's a small world indeed. You are right about the sign mistake, my bad. :( That's why I should never skip the part "if I have made no mistakes"). I was hoping to get an injective map. The setting is: I have a matrix iteration of the form $X_{k+1}=linearF(I,X_k,X_k^2)$, I have a convergence proof for nonnegative matrices, and I'd love to have a general algorithm to read it through this map to prove "for free" that it works for SPD, too.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni A small world indeed. :-) I was hoping to get this reply along with something more useful, but this seems a hard nut to crack.

Comment: @Federico: I see...from its structure it seems that proving convergence of your map directly might be easier, because under multiplicativity type restrictions  on the map, one really ends up with "trivial" solutions of the kind that i put in a comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer, but a collection of observations and ideas, in hopes that it helps someone to get more.

Let us ask a bit more of our function:

> 1. If $AB$ is positive semidefinite, then $\Phi(AB) = \Phi(A)\Phi(B)$.
> 2. $\Phi(H)$ is nonsingular for at least one $H \in \mathcal{H}$. (I think this is quite a reasonable request to make)

Notice that the first of these two requests also means that if $A,B$ commute, then $\Phi(A),\Phi(B)$ commute as well. Using this, we easily see that

$$t\Phi(H) = \Phi(t{\rm I}H) = \Phi(t{\rm I})\Phi(H), \quad \text{for all $H$}.$$

We pick $H$ such that $\Phi(H)$ is nonsingular and get

$$\Phi(t{\rm I}) = t{\rm I}, \quad \text{for all $t \ge 0$}.$$

This also draws a trivial conclusion that

$$\Phi(H^{-1}) = \Phi(H)^{-1}.$$

If $A$ is a matrix whose elements are all equal to $1$, then

$$nf(A) = f(nA) = f(A^2) = f(A)^2.$$

Unfortunately, all-ones matrices are not the only ones with such property, so I cannot get anything more from this (I was hoping to get some insight on $\Phi(A)$, at least for such special $A$).

The preservation of commutativity gave me the following idea. If $A,B \in \mathcal{H}$ commute, then there exist a unitary matrix $U$ and nonnegative diagonal matrices $\Lambda_A,\Lambda_B$ such that
$$A = U \Lambda_A U^*, \quad B = U \Lambda_B U^*.$$
But, since this means that $\Phi(A),\Phi(B)$ also commute, there exist a unitary matrix $V$ and upper triangular matrices $T_A,T_B$ such that
$$\Phi(A) = V T_A V^*, \quad \Phi(B) = V T_B V^*.$$
So, it may make sense to define $\Phi(X)$ as a map $(U,\Lambda) \mapsto (V, T)$, where $X = U \Lambda U^*$ for $U$ unitary and $\Lambda$ nonnegative diagonal, and $\Phi(X) = V T V^*$ for $V$ unitary and $T$ uppertriangular.

The problems with this approach are:

1. defining such map to guarantee that $\Phi(X)$ is nonnegative,
2. property 2 gets hard to prove for noncommutative matrices.

The first problem might be solved by changing the requirements on $V$. Maybe it can be some nonsingular matrix with nonnegative elements (so, not unitary). The question of how to get such matrix remains.

I'm currently at loss for additional ideas. I hope these will help at least a bit.

Comment: I think that the multiplicativity restriction that you mention pretty much forces $\Phi$ to be of the form $X \otimes I$ as I mentioned in my comment to Federico....so....

Comment: "No" was my hunch as well. However, I've managed to find no solid proof for it, so I went looking for such a map, in hopes to either get something useful or get a contradiction (all-ones matrix was one of such tries).